# PHP Smarty Template fails if over a certain size, exhausts PHP memory limit indefinitely

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using PHP Smarty templates for a website.  I noticed that one Smarty based JS file was failing to load today.  At first I thought it was a syntax error, but was able to reduce it down to it failing when it exceeded a certain file size limit.

To be exact, if the file size exceeds 109049 bytes for me, the smarty page will not load.  So at or below that it is fine, and if I type a single extra character and save, it does not.  It comes up empty and the compiled smarty php file is also near empty.

Is there an upper limit, or could it be exceeding some php memory limit somewhere?  The file is about 2990 lines long, and is my largest Smarty tpl file by size.

**EDIT:**

Updating the PHP error reporting didn't help, but adding these two smarty lines did:
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL;

Which give some smarty debugging info below.  The "memory_limit" is being exceeded.  I tried to raise it from 512MB default to basically infinity (10GB), but it always exceeds it.

Why would it be consuming infinite memory?

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2059141120) (tried to allocate 175325 bytes) in /domain.com/lib/Smarty/libs/plugins/modifier.debug_print_var.php on line 36

Comment: I don't think the size has anything to do with it.  I used smarty in the past and had templates with over 10,000 lines in them.  I suspect that something's missing there - most likely inside some conditional.  Enable full error reporting in php and see if you get any errors.

Comment: This for the tip on error.  It give more info, memory limit being exceeded, though I'm not really sure what would cause that.

Comment: I've got memory allocation exceeded errors in the past when I tried to debug-output a huge array (25K entries, each of which being an object with hundreds of fields and some of those being further arrays and objects).  Look through your code to see where you are trying to load too much into memory.  Hint: `mysqli_fetch_all` and `PDO::fetch_all` may be the root cause.